# How do I know whether a local minima is also global?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

In the region $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$ I have 1 radio broadcaster placed in $(x_b,y_b)$ and N receivers. The position of the broadcaster is not known.
The position of each receiver however is known: $(x_i,y_i)$ as is the distance from the receiver to the broadcaster: $d_i$.
There is some noise in the distance measurements that I assume to be normal distributed with mean=0 and the same variance for all receivers.

My goal is to estimate the most likely position of the radio broadcaster: $(x_b,y_b)$.

I do this by minimizing:
$$
SE = \sum_i \left[\sqrt{(x_b - x_i)^2+(y_b - y_i)^2} - d_i\right]^2
$$
using `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.

This approach seems to work fine. However how do I know that the local minima I find is also the global minima?
In this example I can plot $SE(x_b,y_b)$:

[image]

However my real problem is estimating the position: $(x,y,z)$ and the orientation of a camera: $(roll,pitch,yaw)$.
There is no way I can visualize 6D space.
Therefore I am looking for some other way to check whether a found minima is global.

As far as I understand there are only two ways to show that there is only 1 local minima?

**Method I**

Show that
$$
\frac{\partial SE}{\partial x_b} = \frac{\partial SE}{\partial y_b} = 0
$$
only has 1 solution and that all the eigenvalues of the Hessian of SE in this point are positive.

**Method II**

Show that SE is convex by showing that all eigenvalues of the Hessian of SE are positive at all points.

Let us try method I.

I find that:
$$
\frac{\partial SE}{\partial x_b} = \Sigma_i 2 (x_b - x_i) 
\frac{\sqrt{(x_b - x_i)^2 + (y_b - y_i)^2} - d_i}{\sqrt{(x_b - x_i)^2 + (y_b - y_i)^2}}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial SE}{\partial y_b} = \Sigma_i 2 (y_b - y_i) 
\frac{\sqrt{(x_b - x_i)^2 + (y_b - y_i)^2} - d_i}{\sqrt{(x_b - x_i)^2 + (y_b - y_i)^2}}
$$

How many solutions do
$$
\frac{\partial SE}{\partial x_b} = \frac{\partial SE}{\partial y_b} = 0
$$
have?
Difficult to tell, I guess it dependens on the $\{(x_i,y_i,d_i)\}$ values?

Method II seems even harder.

Comment: The distance $d_i$ cannot be negative. So I think it follows rather the absolute value of a normal distribution $|\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)|$

Comment: @NN2: I meant that the noise is normal distributed, not the distance. I assume  that the instrument can both measure too short and too long a distance.

Comment: Ok, it's clearer for me now.

Comment: This function is not convex, so it looks like there isn't a classical simple result to get global optimality here

Comment: Try using a branch and bound global optimization solver, such as BARON.It may succeed if the dimension is not too high.

Comment: How large is $N$?

Comment: @RiverLi: In the real problem (x,y,z), (roll,pitch,yaw): N = 88. In the example problem (x_b,y_b): maybe 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this - although it does *not* guarantee that you found a global optimum - is to apply one (or more) of the Scipy global optimisers and let them run with a very generous amount of iterations/functions evaluations.

Since you only have 6 parameters, optimisers like SHGO, Dual Annealing, etc… *might* be able to explore the parameters space well enough to give you a reasonable probability that you found a very good optimum. Multiple random restarts with a local solver is also a possibility.

But beside a fine/grained brute force attack followed by a local optimisation, I don’t see a way to have a guarantee that your optimum is a global one.

If you have your model formulation in Python and you can post it - together with some data to make it runnable - I’d be curious to give it a try with my personal collection of optimisers.

Answer (score 1):

**SDP relaxation solution.**

The original optimization problem is equivalent to the following one:
\begin{align*}
 (\mathrm{P}) &\min_{x_b,\, y_b;\, \{z_i\}_{i=1}^n} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n [(x_b - x_i)^2 + (y_b - y_i)^2] + \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n 2d_i z_i \\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\quad (x_b - x_i)^2 + (y_b - y_i)^2 \ge z_i^2, \quad i = 1, 2, \cdots, n.
\end{align*}

Let
$$X := \begin{bmatrix}
 x_b \\
 y_b \\
 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 x_b \\
 y_b \\
 1
\end{bmatrix}^\top =  \begin{bmatrix}
 x_b^2 & x_by_b & x_b \\
 x_by_b & y_b^2 & y_b \\
 x_b & y_b & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The problem (P) is written as
\begin{align*}
 (\mathrm{P}1) &\min_{X;\, \{z_i\}_{i=1}^n} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n [X_{11} + X_{22} - 2x_iX_{13} - 2y_iX_{23} + x_i^2 + y_i^2] + \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n 2d_i z_i \\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\quad X_{11} + X_{22} - 2x_iX_{13} - 2y_iX_{23} + x_i^2 + y_i^2\ge z_i^2, \quad i = 1, 2, \cdots, n;\\
 &\qquad\,\, X_{33} = 1, \quad \mathrm{rank}(X) = 1, \quad X \succeq 0.
\end{align*}

If we drop the constraint $\mathrm{rank}(X) = 1$, we turn to solve the SDP relaxation
\begin{align*}
 (\mathrm{P}2) &\min_{X;\, \{z_i\}_{i=1}^n} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n [X_{11} + X_{22} - 2x_iX_{13} - 2y_iX_{23} + x_i^2 + y_i^2] + \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n 2d_i z_i \\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\quad X_{11} + X_{22} - 2x_iX_{13} - 2y_iX_{23} + x_i^2 + y_i^2\ge z_i^2, \quad i = 1, 2, \cdots, n;\\
 &\qquad\,\, X_{33} = 1, \quad X \succeq 0.
\end{align*}

We can use CVX+Matlab to solve (P2).
If the solution to (P2) has a rank one, then we obtain the global minimum of the original problem.

I tested some $n= 20$ randomly generated $x_i$'s, $y_i$'s, and $d$'s. In these examples, it works well.